# Android6.0 WebView shows blank page

Tags: java, android, webview

I have tried to load a page with webView, and it just shows an empty page on my cellphone. Here are the codes and classes.
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bobqiu.http_01" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.bobqiu.http_01.MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webview1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="72dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

HttpThread.java

```
package com.example.bobqiu.http_01;

    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.webkit.WebView;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;

    /**
     * Created by Bobqiu on 2016/9/22.
     */

    public class HttpThread extends Thread {
        private String url;

        private WebView webView;

        private Handler handler;

        public HttpThread(String url,WebView webView,Handler handler){
            this.url = url;
            this.webView = webView;
            this.handler = handler;
        }
        public void run(){
            try {
                URL httpUrl = new URL(url);
                try {
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) httpUrl.openConnection();
                    connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    String str;
                    while((str = reader.readLine())!=null){
                        sb.append(str);
                    }

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {                     
                        webView.loadData(sb.toString(),"text/html;
                        charset=utf-8",null);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.bobqiu.http_01;

import android.Manifest;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView= (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        int permissionCheckContextCompat.
        checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
        System.out.println("!!!!!"+permissionCheck);//it shows 0 in console
        new HttpThread("https://m.baidu.com/",webView,handler).start();
    }
}
```

I have also tried the webView.loadDataWithBaseURL method, still doesn't work...
Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no need to load data in a SubThread...

you can log the stringbuilder info before webView loads it

webView.loadData(String url) works well

－－－update 
i try to run your code (23 and 19):

[image]

Comment: I suppose you mean webView.loadUrl(Strng url)... I tried it and it works well. Thanks. But I still want to understand the difference between loadData by stringBuffer and loadUrl directly. Also The code above works just fine in the emulator(Android 4.4.2), but fail to show in my real phone(Android 6.0). Is there any difference between the two version? If it is about the runtime check in Android 6.0, I have checked and the result is 0, which means it is permitted.

Answer (score 1):

Add **internet permission** in you manifest. Without it your application will not be able to access internet services.

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
...
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application ...
</manifest>
```

Edited -

In android M and above you have to ask permissions from the user at runtime. Before calling

```
new HttpThread("https://m.baidu.com/",webView,handler).start();
```

run this code for granting permissions -

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Should we show an explanation?
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                            Manifest.permission.INTERNET)) {
                        // Explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
                    }
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},
                            1);
                    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
                    // app-defined int constant
                    return;
                }else {
                    new HttpThread("https://m.baidu.com/",webView,handler).start();
                }
            }else {
                new HttpThread("https://m.baidu.com/",webView,handler).start();
            }
```

**And override this method -**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                new HttpThread("https://m.baidu.com/",webView,handler).start();
            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                Snackbar.make(parent, "Click on allow to Access Internet in you application", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("CLOSE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                            }
                        })
                        .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_purple
                        )).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

After this it should run in your Android M phone too. Hope it works.

Comment: sorry, I have added it but it doesn't work... I am wondering if it is the version of Android system, it works fine on emulator(Android 4.4.2), but not work on the real phone(Android 6.0), anyway thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try loading data like this:

```
webView.loadData(sb.toString(),"text/html",UTF-8);
```

or this:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("",sb.toString(),"text/html",UTF-8,"");
```