# How to ask permission to make phone call from Android from Android version Marshmallow onwards?

Tags: java, android, phone-call, runtime-permissions

I am trying to make a phone call from Android, and I've set run time permissions as well. And it asks whether to allow making phone calls. But when I press allow, the app crashes:

This is how I implemented it:

```
private static final int REQUEST_PHONE_CALL = 1;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "+918511812660"));

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);
    }
    else
    {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
else
{
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PHONE_CALL: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {

            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I obtain in logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, 
     request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} 
     to activity {com.devpost.airway/com.devpost.airway.activities.MainActivity}: 
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
     'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.toString()' on a null object reference

      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3733)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3776)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
    'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.toString()' on a null object reference
      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1485)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3930)
      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3890)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:856)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4213)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4181)
      at com.devpost.airway.activities.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:140)
      at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:6582)
      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6460)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3729)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3776) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

What is possibly causing this?

Comment: Inside an Activity or a Fragment?

Comment: you can check this for your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39646644/6812027

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The stack trace seems to indicate that your permissions flow is working ok, but the call to `startActivity` from `onRequestPermissionsResult()` is crashing. Is the `Intent` you're passing to `startActivity` set correctly? I can't see it being set in that part of the code.

Note also that `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission` handles the SDK version checking on your behalf, so you should be able to use

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);
}
else
{
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

by itself, without the wrapping SDK version check code.

Comment: thank you, the problem was caused as the Intent was not set properly, I am upvoting the answer as it helped to fix the problem .

Comment: Hy @OBX Can you explain in which section Intent was not set properly. I have some issue. Thank you

Comment: Excellent answer. This worked for Android Jelly Bean 4.1.

Answer (score 44):

I would better suggest to use ACTION_DIAL rather than ACTION_CALL while constructing Intent to call a particular number . Using ACTION_DIAL , you will need no call permissions in your app, as ACTION_DIAL opens the dialer with the number already entered, and further allows the user to decide whether to actually make the call or modify the phone number before calling or not call at all.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "Your Phone_number"));// Initiates the Intent 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Perfect!
Thanks

Comment: this is the best answer!

Answer (score 6):

You need to create your `Intent` in `onRequestPermissionsResult`

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PHONE_CALL: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "+918511812660"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {

            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add new method

```
public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
    for (String permission : permissions) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
}
```

add this in Global

```
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1; 
String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE};
```

and write below code in onCreate

```
if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to not use phone_call permission for that action. Google Play console will alert you that you should avoid asking for unnecessary permission from the user. This is a better approach:

```
/**
 * Make a phone call. Send to the phone app
 *
 * @param phoneNumber the phone number to call
 */
private fun performPhoneCall(phoneNumber: String) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
    intent.data = Uri.parse("tel:$phoneNumber")
    try {
        context.startActivity(intent)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        displayErrorMessage()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `onRequestPermissionsResult` to below, you basically need to create the `intent` first and then call it on permission granted. That's where you are doing it wrong.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PHONE_CALL : {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "+918511812660"));

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void makePhoneCall() {
    String number = items;
    if (number.trim().length() > 0) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_CALL);
        } else {
            String dial = "tel:" + number;
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial)));
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter Phone Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CALL) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            makePhoneCall();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission DENIED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a bit of text to explain how this answer is helpful. Explain which changes you did etcetera.