# Not able to get Local Notification when app is not in background in Android

Tags: android, localnotification

I have prepared demo to receive local notification daily like alarm, but its working in some device and not working in some other device (Like OPPO, MI) when app is not in background not receiving notification.

Can any one please help to provide source code or any reference link to resolve this issue.

Comment: share your code so we can help you fix it

Comment: Hi, I have used this link code.

http://www.concretepage.com/android/android-alarm-clock-tutorial-to-schedule-and-cancel-alarmmanager-pendingintent-and-wakefulbroadcastreceiver-example

Answer (score 0):

Mostly notification working on some devices because of two reasons:

> 1) If device API level is 6.0+
>
> 2) Account Sync not working.

1) If device API level is 6.0+ then you need to write permission handler code [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40126024/3522570)

2)Account Sync not working. go to settings > then select Google account > and click on Sync button. If on Google account it showing `!` this symbol then that means problem is in your device account sync.

Comment: Local Notification not working is the device with OS 5.1.1
It's only not working when app is not in background. If its in background then receiving notification.